# Error while running postgres container "Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/lib/postgresql/data."

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell, docker

I'm trying to run a postgres docker container on Windows 10.

I've installed postgres using the Linux container as I couldn't do so using the Windows container.

While running the below in powershell

```
docker run -d --name pg-flowthru --env-file ./database/env.list -p 5432:5432 --rm -v ${PWD}:/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

(env.list contains database credentials), I'm getting the below error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/lib/postgresql/data. 
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

C drive is already in the "Shared Drives" in Docker Desktop

I think this may be an issue with path, but I'm new to docker and can't figure it out.

Comment: You're trying to pass three paths to the `docker run -v` option; it only takes two.  (Either `$PWD` or `/docker/volumes/postgres`, probably, but not both.)

Comment: But the exact same command, with ```$HOME``` instead of ```${PWD}:``` works on Mac (and probably linux). When using ```$HOME``` instead of ```${PWD}:``` on Windows, a container ID is generated, but no container actually runs (when executing ```docker ps -a```).

Comment: Like `-v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, with only one colon?  The extra colon makes a big difference.

Comment: Executing the above on Windows creates a container ID, but nothing actually runs when doing ```docker ps -a```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From here](https://glenmccallum.com/2018/06/07/postgresql-csharp-docker/)

[More info here](http://www.lukaszewczak.com/2016/09/run-postgresql-using-docker-with.html)

A volume has to be created first:

```
docker volume create postgresql-volume
```

The postgres container can now be run using the previously created volume:

```
docker run -d --name pg-flowthru --env-file ./database/env.list -p 5432:5432 -v 'postgresql-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data' postgres
```

Listing the running containers now shows the above container running.